# Memory usage on my Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

I have been asked to look at the performance of a Windows 10 64 bit laptop that seems to be "slow".

This laptop has an Intel Celeron 2.2Ghz CPU with 2GB RAM and on startup is already using 65% before any user applications are started.

The only user-defined service that is included in Start Up is AVG anti-virus.

I've looked at RAM Map and I don't see anything obvious that is causing such high memory usage.

Once we launch our preferred Chrome browser, memory usage jumps to 80% which seems quite high. (Chrome has only Ad Block extension)

I've also checked disk defragmentation and there are no problems there as it runs weekly.

Is this high memory usage expected for Windows 10 running on 2GB? If it is that is fine, we can hopefully add more memory to give things a boost

[image: RAM Map 1]
[image: RAM Map 2]

Comment: *"Is this high memory usage expected for Windows 10 running on 2GB?"*  Yes, for the most part.  I have an old laptop with similar specs (dual-core with 2 GB of RAM), and while I usually see performance a little bit better than yours, under comparable scenarios most of the memory remains in use.  I do a few things to mitigate it, though:  I am using the 32-bit version of Windows 10, running an office suite that is less resource-intensive (Office 2010), and using Firefox instead of Chrome.  Mozilla's browser is typically easier on the battery as well as the RAM.

Comment: Your system simply requires more memory in its current configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal Windows 10 memory usage you see. [Microsoft increased the RAM requirement from 1 GB to 2 GB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/Windows-10-specifications#sysreqs) for new devices:

> **RAM:** New device: 2 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 64-bit

And 2 GB are really be minimum to get Windows 10 working because it runs so much tools that require RAM (shell, startmenu/screen, action center. Cortana, notifications from apps).

You can't really fix it, except you install [StartIsBack++](http://www.startisback.com/), set the option to not load any Shell elements

[image]

and uninstall nearly all apps.

Comment: Thanks, I've now upgraded to 3GB RAM which should hopefully help